# How do I link a second view controller to a random image generator in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, macos, uiviewcontroller

I'm having trouble working out how to stop my random image generator crashing when it reaches the last index in the array. I'm trying to get it to load a second view controller that I have created with a reset button that reloads the initial image generator but can't quite work out how to code it in.
I'm not looking to make the images continuously loop, I need them to deplete and then reload again shuffled.

i.e. App loads -> auto shuffles the array -> button pressed until images depleted -> second view controller with a reset button to go back to the main view controller, auto shuffling the array and regenerating a different variation of the same images.

I'm quite new to coding so I'm pretty happy I've managed to get as much as I have so far and very much appreciate any assistance with the road block I've hit.

The code I have so far:

```swift
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mainImageView: UIImageView!
    
    var imageMain = 0

    var array = [ #imageLiteral(resourceName: "raven-988218_1280"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "halloween-2905531_1280"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bird-skull-4433244_1280"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "candles-1868640_1280"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tombstone-2542946_1280"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "fantasy-2847724_1280") ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        mainImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "start-image")

        array.shuffle()        
    }    
    
    @IBAction func randomButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //print(imageMain)
            
        mainImageView.image = array[imageMain]
            
        imageMain += 1
        //alternative for random = mainImageArray.randomElement()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I see it right if `imageMain` reaches `array.count - 1`, it will be reset to 0?

Comment: Just put this line and 

if imageMain < array.count
            {
                mainImageView.image = array[imageMain]
                imageMain += 1
            }